# How to use input parameters in filter_() in ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) wrapper.

I want to use the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter to extract a cropped section of the video file; I want the section's size to be half the dimensions of the input.

According to ffmpeg's documentation, I can use the input parameters `in_w` and `in_h` like so:

`crop=1/2*in_w:1/2*in_h`
(or
`crop=w=1/2*in_w:h=1/2*in_h` with named parameters)

However, I struggle to find how to use them in ffmpeg-python. I figured I could pass them as standard arguments like so:
`filter_('crop', '1/2*in_w:1/2*in_h')`
but I seem to misunderstand how direct arguments work here because this does not work.

Obviously, I can't use keyword arguments either like so:

`filter_('crop', w=1/2*in_w, h=1/2*in_h)`

because they're interpreted as undefined names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was actually very close. While testing more possibilities, I found out that all I needed to do was to send the keywords as strings:

```
(ffmpeg
 .input("input.mp4")
 .filter_('crop', w='1/2*in_w', h='1/2*in_h')
 .output("output.mp4")
 .run()
 )
```